# SSRS Report - Group By Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm currently trying to understand how works SSRS on VS 2010 Shell version.
I have a table set up like below:

[image: Picture One]

And on the preview Page, it's give me something like that:

[image: Picture One]

However, I would like to be able to reproduce a formatting where all my different countries are on different column

Do you know how I can create something like that?
I'm very new on this software so please do not hesitate to give me many indication of which step to follow....^^

Comment: use matrix object(it is similar to pivot in excel) instead of table

Comment: Yup, use a matrix object - and set the column groups to countrygroup. FYI its sometimes easier to drag the field names into the row or column groups in the design pane than to drag them into the object.

Comment: Perfect it's exactly what I wanted Thanks guys! :)